# How to set a variable within a batch program into the first line of a text file and overwrite this line upon the batch file having an updated variable

Tags: batch-file, variables

Basically I want to make it so that when the player within my games makes a name, it saves the name variable into a text file. Then within the txt file, upon the loading the save file, the game will look at the text file labled "name.txt" for instance, and inside will contain the player name upon which will be extracted by some means so the new save can be loaded, but for other player variables such as wealth or location, those are dynamic variables and may need to be changed often, so what I was suggesting is that how would I constantly update this "weath.txt" file and/or "location.txt" file for instance and overwrite the previous text lines containing there previous location. As for how I would set the variable of any given player characteristic such as its name, I have used this patch of code to no avail:

```
    @echo off
    :start
    set /p name=">"
    (@echo off %name%)>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\gamedir\name.txt"
    SET name=

    for /f "delims=" %%i in (name.txt) do call :setname %%i
    echo final name = %name%
    goto exit

    :Setname
    Set name=%name% %1%
    goto :eof

    :exit
    pause
rem showing result which appears to do nothing 
    echo %name%
```

As for extracting this variable upon a load game, I have absolutely no idea how to do that at all. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Regard that argument references are `%1` but not `%1%`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple enough way to handle saving and loading is to store game data in a bat file, then call it when it's time to load.

The below subroutine example prefixes any variable to be saved with `Save.` so that it can be output using the set command within a for loop, to ensure only the desired variables are saved.

```
:Save
REM refresh the save file
    >"%name%.bat" Echo @Echo off
REM output all requied values prefixed with Save. using the Set Command to allow easy loading
    For /F "UsebackQ Tokens=* Delims=" %%S in (`"Set Save."`) Do >>"%name%.bat" Echo Set "%%~S"
REM Finalise the save with a return to the calling script
    >>"%name%.bat" Echo Goto :EOF
Exit /B

:Load
REM Calls the save file which contains commands to set all relevant variables
    CALL "%name%.bat"
Exit /B
```

You can easily support multiple characters by storing them in their own folder and using `DIR` to [display them and an input method to select them.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOgzcTglMcc&t=6s)

```
`DIR "%TEMP%\GameName\characters" /B /P`
```